# Is there anything I can do about the redundant and annoying "Background Items Added" notifications that keep appearing?

Tags: macos, notifications

I'm running macOS 13.6.5 and I keep getting annoying and hard to dismiss "Background Items Added" notifications for apps that are already installed and have already set up their background items. These apps are fully updated, so if there is something they're doing wrong in creating their background items then the developers haven't addressed it yet and I need to find another solution other than updating them.

I've considered creating a special "Focus" mode that whitelists every single app I've already given permission to display notifications, which is annoying to have to maintain, but then these background item notifications just continue sitting around taking up space in the Notification Center and pushing down all of the widgets I actually want to see until I manually dismiss them, so it's only a half solution.

Is there anything I can do to stop these from coming up?

Comment: I'm running 13.6.5 and don't get a single notification like this, but my laptop doesn't go through a lot of software churn.  These apps repeatedly cause the OS to post the message?

Comment: Might help if you said which apps.

Comment: @Gilby The two that seem to trigger it the most often are background processes for SoundSource / Rogue Amoeba's audio capture engine, and VMware Fusion. But there are several others I'm forgetting. It comes up so often for me that it all starts to blur together.

Comment: Can confirm what you are seeing with VMware - but I only see this the first time I open Fusion after a reboot. And not surprised by Rogue Amoeba's ACE. Both use unusual system/kernel extensions (I don't understand the specifics) and macOS is warning potential dangers. If problem for you, I suggest you contact the developers or their user forums. I don't think you can stop those alerts.

Comment: Fusion: See https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Fusion-13-and-Tech-Preview-Background-Items-Added-Notification/m-p/2979161 and https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Fusion-13-on-macOS-Ventura-How-to-disable-recurrent/m-p/2945120. Has reasons why it happens and an unsupported workaround.